# VB.NET Databinding Label not listening to PropertyChanged

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have a label which is databound to a Property in a Class which returns the highest number from another class. The numbers are filled into the other class from 6 text fields.

The 6 properties for the numbers all raise the PropertyChanged event when modified with the Parameter "BestThrow.Distance" as can be seen below:

```
    Public Property Distance() As String
        Get
            If Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Then
                If (m_Distance > 0) Then
                    Return m_Distance
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If

            ElseIf Status = ThrowStatus.Pass Then
                Return "PASS"
            ElseIf Status = ThrowStatus.Foul Then
                Return "FOUL"
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If (value.Length > 0) Then
                If (IsNumeric(value)) Then
                    m_Distance = value
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                ElseIf (value = "FOUL") Then
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Foul
                ElseIf (value = "PASS") Then
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Pass
                Else
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                    m_Distance = Nothing
                End If
            Else
                m_Distance = Nothing
                Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
            End If
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("BestThrow.Distance"))
        End Set
    End Property
```

The Property which the label is bound to is as follows:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property BestThrow() As Object
        Get
            Dim bt = Throws.Where(Function(t) t.Status = ThrowStatus.Valid).OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.Distance).First()
            If (IsNothing(bt.Distance)) Then
                bt.Distance = "0"
            End If

            Return bt
        End Get
    End Property
```

For the sake of providing all the information the Databinding for the label is as follows
`best.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", athlete, "BestThrow.Distance", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))`

When I add in the first Distance the label updates fine and displays Distance(0).Distance as expected, however when I change the other 5 values the label will not update. If, however, I then modify the first value again it will recalculate the BestThrow and display the correct distance.

I have also tried manually raising the event using a button on the form which also did not work.

From using watch values I can see that when requested the BestThrow Property is spitting out the correct values, it just seems the label only is interested in an event from the first Throw.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Current Code:

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

    Public Class Competition
        Public Sub New()
            Competitors = New List(Of Competitor)()
        End Sub
        Public Property Competitors() As List(Of Competitor)
            Get
                Return m_Competitors
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of Competitor))
                m_Competitors = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Competitors As List(Of Competitor)
        Public ReadOnly Property CurrentPlacings() As List(Of Competitor)
            Get
                Return Competitors.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.BestThrow).ToList()


            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
    Public Class Competitor

        Public Sub New()
            Throws = New List(Of [Throw])()
        End Sub
        Public Property athletenum() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_athnum
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                m_athnum = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Athnum As Integer

        Public Property FirstName() As String
            Get
                Return m_FirstName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_FirstName = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_FirstName As String
        Public Property LastName() As String
            Get
                Return m_LastName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_LastName = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_LastName As String
        Public Property compNumber() As String
            Get
                Return m_compNumb
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_compNumb = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_compNumb As String
        Public Property club() As String
            Get
                Return m_club
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_club = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_club As String
        Public Property Throws() As List(Of [Throw])
            Get
                Return m_Throws
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of [Throw]))
                m_Throws = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Throws As List(Of [Throw])
        Public ReadOnly Property BestThrow() As String
            Get
                Dim list As IList(Of [Throw]) = (From t As [Throw] In Throws Select t Where t.Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Order By t.Distance Descending).ToList()
                If (list.Count > 0) Then
                    If (IsNothing(list(0).Distance)) Then
                        Return "0"
                    Else
                        Return list(0).Distance
                    End If

                End If
                Return "0"
            End Get
        End Property
        Public ReadOnly Property getLabel()
            Get
                Return compNumber & " " & LastName & ", " & FirstName & vbCrLf & club
            End Get
        End Property
        Public Property currentPlace
            Get
                Return m_curplace
            End Get
            Set(value)
                m_curplace = value
            End Set

        End Property
        Private m_curplace As Integer
    End Class
    Public Enum ThrowStatus
        Valid
        Pass
        Foul
    End Enum
    Public Class [Throw]
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        'Throw Status
        Public Property Status() As ThrowStatus
            Get
                Return m_Status
            End Get
            Set(value As ThrowStatus)
                m_Status = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Status As ThrowStatus

        'Throw Distance
        Public Property Distance() As String
            Get
                Dim value As String = Me.m_Distance
                If Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Then
                    If (m_Distance > 0) Then
                        value = m_Distance
                    Else
                        value = Nothing
                    End If

                ElseIf Status = ThrowStatus.Pass Then
                    value = "PASS"
                ElseIf Status = ThrowStatus.Foul Then
                    value = "FOUL"
                Else
                    value = Nothing
                End If
                If (value  Me.m_Distance) Then
                    Me.Distance = value
                End If
                Return value
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If (value.Length > 0) Then
                    If (IsNumeric(value)) Then
                        m_Distance = value
                        Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                    ElseIf (value = "FOUL") Then
                        Status = ThrowStatus.Foul
                    ElseIf (value = "PASS") Then
                        Status = ThrowStatus.Pass
                    Else
                        Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                        m_Distance = Nothing
                    End If
                Else
                    m_Distance = Nothing
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                End If
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("BestThrow"))
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Distance As Decimal
        Public Property attempt() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_attempt
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                m_attempt = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_attempt As Integer

    End Class
```

Current binding:
`best.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", athlete, "BestThrow", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))`

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I don't like seeing properties calculating the return value. I think this should be done in a method. (It might be okay in a read only property.) Just my opinion. What I find strange is that the getter for `Distance` depends on `Status`, and the setter acts more like a setter for `Status`.

Your binding expects a `PropertyDescriptor` named `Distance`. You return a `String`, and as you know the string class doesn't have a property named `Distance`.

```
best.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", athlete, "BestThrow.Distance", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

**Option 1**

For this to work you'll need to do it like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property BestThrow() As TYPE_OF_YOUR_CLASS
    Get
        'IMPORTANT: 
        'This approach requires at least ONE matching object and 
        'ONE item returned. If not, the binding will fail.
        Return (From t As TYPE_OF_YOUR_CLASS In throws Select t Where t.Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Order By t.Distance Ascending).First()
    End Get
End Property
```

**Option 2**

Another option is to just bind to the `BestThrow` property:

```
best.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", athlete, "BestThrow", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

And change your property to this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property BestThrow() As String
    Get
        'NOTE: 
        'Do not use First() as this will fail if no matching items are found.
        'We use ToList() and check the count property.
        Dim list As IList(Of TYPE_OF_YOUR_CLASS) = (From t As TYPE_OF_YOUR_CLASS In throws Select t Where t.Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Order By t.Distance Ascending).ToList()
        If (list.Count > 0) Then
            Return list(0).Distance
        End If
        Return "0"
    End Get
End Property
```

**EDIT**

To be honest I think this is bad designed. Please look in detail at this approach:

```
Public Class Athlete
    'TODO: Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New(athleteNumber As Integer, Optional firstName As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal lastName As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal club As String = Nothing)
        Me.m_athleteNumber = athleteNumber 
        Me.m_firstName = If((firstName Is Nothing), String.Empty, firstName)
        Me.m_lastName = If((lastName Is Nothing), String.Empty, lastName)
        Me.m_club = If((club Is Nothing), String.Empty, club)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property AthleteNumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.m_athleteNumber
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Club() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_club
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.m_club = value
            'TODO: If changed raise property changed.
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_firstName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.m_firstName = value
            'TODO: If changed raise property changed.
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_lastName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.m_lastName = value
            'TODO: If changed raise property changed.
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Concat(Me.m_firstName, " ", Me.m_lastName).Trim()
    End Function

    Private m_athleteNumber As Integer
    Private m_club As String
    Private m_firstName As String
    Private m_lastName As String

End Class

Public Class Competitor
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New(athlete As Athlete, Optional competitorNumber As String = Nothing)
        If (athlete Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("athlete")
        End If
        Me.m_athlete = athlete
        Me.m_bestThrow = 0D
        Me.m_competitorNumber = If((competitorNumber Is Nothing), String.Empty, competitorNumber)
        Me.m_curplace = 0
        Me.m_throws = New ObjectCollection(Of [Throw])
        AddHandler Me.m_throws.CollectionChanged, New CollectionChangeEventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnThrowCollectionChanged)
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public ReadOnly Property Athlete() As Athlete
        Get
            Return Me.m_athlete
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property BestThrow() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.m_bestThrow
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property CompetitorNumber() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_competitorNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If (value <> Me.m_competitorNumber) Then
                Me.m_competitorNumber = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("CompetitorNumber")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CurrentPlace() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.m_curplace
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If (value <> Me.m_curplace) Then
                Me.m_curplace = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPlace")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Throws() As ObjectCollection(Of [Throw])
        Get
            Return Me.m_throws
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub OnThrowCollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As CollectionChangeEventArgs)
        Dim list As IList(Of [Throw]) = (From t As [Throw] In Me.m_throws Select t Where t.Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Order By t.Distance Descending).ToList()
        Dim bestThrow As Decimal = If((list.Count > 0), list(0).Distance, 0D)
        If (Me.m_bestThrow <> bestThrow) Then
            Me.m_bestThrow = bestThrow
            Me.RaisePropertyChanged("BestThrow")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        If (Not Me.PropertyChangedEvent Is Nothing) Then
            Me.PropertyChangedEvent.Invoke(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private m_athlete As Athlete
    Private m_bestThrow As Decimal
    Private m_competitorNumber As String
    Private m_curplace As Integer
    Private m_throws As ObjectCollection(Of [Throw])

End Class

Public Class [Throw]

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal status As ThrowStatus = ThrowStatus.Valid, Optional distance As Decimal = 0D)
        Me.m_status = status
        Me.m_distance = Math.Max(distance, 0D)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Status() As ThrowStatus
        Get
            Return Me.m_status
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Distance() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.m_distance
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Select Case Me.m_status
            Case ThrowStatus.Valid
                Return Me.m_distance.ToString("N2")
            Case ThrowStatus.Pass
                Return "PASS"
            Case ThrowStatus.Foul
                Return "FOUL"
            Case Else
                Return 0D.ToString("N2")
        End Select
    End Function

    Private m_attempt As Integer
    Private m_distance As Decimal
    Private m_status As ThrowStatus

End Class

Public Class ObjectCollection(Of T)
    Inherits Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)

    Public Event CollectionChanged As CollectionChangeEventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub ClearItems()
        MyBase.ClearItems()
        Me.RaiseCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeAction.Refresh, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
        If (item Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("item")
        ElseIf (Me.Contains(item)) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Item duplicate.", "item")
        End If
        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
        Me.RaiseCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeAction.Add, item)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnCollectionChanged(e As CollectionChangeEventArgs)
        If (Not Me.CollectionChangedEvent Is Nothing) Then
            Me.CollectionChangedEvent.Invoke(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RaiseCollectionChanged(action As CollectionChangeAction, item As T)
        Me.OnCollectionChanged(New CollectionChangeEventArgs(action, item))
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveItem(index As Integer)
        Dim item As T = Me.Item(index)
        MyBase.RemoveItem(index)
        Me.RaiseCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeAction.Remove, item)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub SetItem(index As Integer, item As T)
        Throw New NotSupportedException()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Enum ThrowStatus As Integer
    Valid = 0 '<- This is the default value.
    Pass = 1
    Foul = 2
End Enum
```

The following code are tested and works. Drop a `Button` and a `TextBox` onto a `Form` and append:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        Me.InitializeComponent()

        Me.competitor = New Competitor(New Athlete(1, "John", "Smith", "Team JS"), "CP_1")
        Me.competitor.Throws.Add(New [Throw](distance:=123.3472D))
        Me.competitor.Throws.Add(New [Throw](distance:=424.1234D))
        Me.competitor.Throws.Add(New [Throw](distance:=242.1234D))

        Dim b As New Binding("Text", Me.competitor, "BestThrow", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never)
        AddHandler b.Format, New ConvertEventHandler(AddressOf Me._FormatBinding)
        Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(b)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.competitor.Throws.Add(New [Throw](distance:=845.4365D))
    End Sub

    Private Sub _FormatBinding(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
        If ((TypeOf e.Value Is Decimal) AndAlso (e.DesiredType Is GetType(String))) Then
            e.Value = CDec(e.Value).ToString("N2")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private competitor As Competitor

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I chose to go down the path of Option one as I wish to keep the status and the distance seperate for future purposes, however, currently the text field will be set to either a valid decimal, PASS or FOUL and in the design of the form it is not really practical to have a seperate element for the status.

After making the suggested changes the issue with the label still remains. I don't think the issue here is related to the Classes but more so the databinding in the label.

Comment: @mrtechguy I've edited my answer and I think this will fix your problem.

Comment: I made a couple of changes, firstly I changed ascending to descending (as I need to longest throw). I also added in a check if list(0).Distance is nothing to return "0". In the Set for the throw I changed the event args to bestthrow and I have changed the databinding for the label to just bestthrow, however I only seem to get an initial update (on form load) to "0" but when changing any of the distances there seems to be no update to the label.

Comment: @mrtechguy Can you update your question with the current code?

Comment: Are you sure this is the `exact` code? It breaks at this part `If (value  Me.m_Distance) Then`. In VS, please click on "My Project", "Compile" tab, and under "Compile options" be sure "Option Strict" is on. At this point you'll have a bunch of errors. Fix these errors and update with current code.

Comment: I have posted the entire source on dropbox here. The files you are looking at are throws.vb and throwscomp.vb Please excuse the messy coding, this is my first project and I will later be going through and optimising the code and fixing up a fair few of the rookie mistakes.  When you first load the program you will have to go to Options > Database File and setup the location of the Database Files folder included. The event you are currently looking at is Mens DT. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bjzzy04uudp73nq/Y67tSBhvRT

Comment: @mrtechguy I'm sorry, but I don't have the time to look into this at the moment. But I hope you take your time and look at my approach as this is a more "correct" structuring. PS: You could try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).